# How to write a packaging task using Python in a virtual environment?

Tags: python, pypi

## I wanna do this

I try to packaging python code with read this site.

https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Sure, I could do it manually. However, I want to make it a little easier from the second time.

## What I tried

`.vscode/tasks.json` is this.

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "python -m build"
        }
    ]
}
```

## Tried result

As you can imagine, this task fails.

```
> Executing task: python -m build <

Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
The terminal process "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe -Command python -m build" terminated with exit code: 1.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

## The answer I want

Is it possible to avoid specifying an absolute path and specify Python in a virtual environment?

Is there a better way?

## Environment

[image]

Comment: The error suggests Python is not in your PATH, which would be necessary execute any virtualenv. I don't think you should lock your build process to your IDE, though

Comment: @OneCricketeer Does that mean it's better to use any CI tools?

Comment: Probably, yes, like Github Actions. Or use tools like Poetry within your project

Comment: Thank you! I just tried `poetry build`. It was very comfortable. I'm going to use `poetry` habitually from now on.